# How to compare various date formats stored as nvarchar in a column with the getdate() in SQL Server

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

When examined the values in the table, I found that few values are stored as `2015-03-20T06:06:46` and few values are stored as `11/25/2014`. So now how to compare these both values in where clause with `getdate()`

```
SELECT B.Value
FROM table1 A WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN table1 B WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.id = B.id
WHERE
    A.Name = 'COMPLETED_AT' 
    AND CONVERT(smalldatetime, A.Value) < GETDATE() - 30
    AND B.Name = 'RESULT'
```

Getting error message

> Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type

when executing the above query

Example table structure

```
ID  Name           Value
1   Result         R12344
1   Completed_At   2015-03-20T06:06:46
2   Result         R23445
2   Completed_At   2014-03-20T06:06:46
3   Result         R83261
3   Completed_At   11/25/2014
```

Column value is of `nvarchar(400)` datatype

The query result should display the values of result name type which have been made an entry of more than 30 days.

Looking forward in hearing from you.

Comment: when i run the below query only records entered in year 2014 are not being displayed only for year 2015

With Result As
(SELECT B.Value as Value,

case LEN(A.value)
when 10 then A.Value
else 
substring((SUBSTRING(A.Value,1,10)),6,2)+'/'
+substring((SUBSTRING(A.Value,1,10)),9,2)+'/'
+substring((SUBSTRING(A.Value,1,10)),1,4)
end as CompletedDate

FROM table1 A WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN table1 B WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.id=B.id
WHERE
A.Name = 'COMPLETED_AT'                 
AND
B.Name = 'VALUE')
Select VALUE,CompletedDate from Result
where CompletedDate < CONVERT(nVARCHAR(400), GETDATE()-30, 101)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If you have dates - then **store them** as `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` !!

Comment: Looks like one of those awesome EAV models. _We don't need no stinkin datatypes!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got answer to my query by myself after going through the link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

```
    CONVERT(nvarchar(400),A.value,126) < CONVERT(nvarchar(400),GETDATE()-30,126)
```

When i have used the above value at the where clause i didnt get any error and also the result is also correct

Comment: You'll have to continue to fix these errors over and over again until you select the correct datatype

Comment: The column data type should be nvarchar as per our requirement as we store all the details in that main table and we would be accessing it via views from there. that column stores the user details like name,contact details, joining date etc.

Comment: Yes you have an EAV data model with all of it's associated issues.